# Output from fitted after loglm

Tags: r, statistics

I am trying to reproduce some log-linear modeling analysis from [Agresti's Categorical Data Analysis (3rd ed.)](http://www.stat.ufl.edu/~aa/cda/cda.html) [CDA] using the `loglm` function from the `MASS` package:

```
library(MASS)

# read in the data: http://www.stat.ufl.edu/~aa/cda/data.html
dfX = read.table(textConnection('a c m r g count 
1 1 1 1 1 405      
1 1 1 2 1  23      
1 2 1 1 1  13      
1 2 1 2 1   2      
2 1 1 1 1   1      
2 1 1 2 1   0      
2 2 1 1 1   1      
2 2 1 2 1   0      
1 1 2 1 1 268
1 1 2 2 1  23
1 2 2 1 1 218
1 2 2 2 1  19
2 1 2 1 1  17
2 1 2 2 1   1
2 2 2 1 1 117
2 2 2 2 1  12
1 1 1 1 2 453
1 1 1 2 2  30
1 2 1 1 2  28
1 2 1 2 2   1
2 1 1 1 2   1
2 1 1 2 2   1
2 2 1 1 2   1
2 2 1 2 2   0
1 1 2 1 2 228
1 1 2 2 2  19
1 2 2 1 2 201
1 2 2 2 2  18
2 1 2 1 2  17
2 1 2 2 2   8
2 2 2 1 2 133
2 2 2 2 2  17'), header = TRUE)

llACM = loglm(count ~ c + a + m, data = dfX)
summary(llACM)
fitted(llACM)
```

But I am having difficulty understanding what the `.Within. =` means, and how I can get a predicted contingency table as given in CDA on page 323.

Comment: Please provide a *useful* link to the page of interest. There are dozens of links on the page you ref'd.  Next, where did you get a `.Within.` item?  Neither `summary.loglm` nor `fitted.loglm` has such a thing so far as I can tell.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft Did you try running the code?

Comment: No, I just ran an example from the MASS help pages. I'll try yours out.

Answer (score 0):

Really a long comment:

I ran your example, and took a look at things like `fitted.loglm` which consists of the following code:

```
{
    if (!is.null(object$fit)) 
        return(unclass(object$fit))
    cat("Re-fitting to get fitted values\n")
    unclass(update(object, fitted = TRUE, keep.frequencies = FALSE)$fitted)
}
```

`update` generates all the info that goes into `object$fitted` .  I compared all sorts of data in the MASS example

```
minn38a <- xtabs(f ~ ., minn38)
fm <- loglm(~ 1 + 2 + 3 + 4, minn38a)
```

And about the only guess I can make is that your data is not properly dimensioned--or the fitting model adds a needed dimension, and this extra dim is given the default name `.Within.` .   My suggestion would be to read the MASS book, or dig up info on `glm` fitting models.  I agree that the explanations of the dimensions defined in the fitted dataset are somewhat lacking.

Comment: Carl, thanks, but the data is included so please help me understand, if only vaguely, what you might mean by not properly dimensioned.